# Is there a vanilla JavaScript way to change the value of an input field

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to achieve is for the value of the `id="origin"` input field to be updated as you type in the `id="pickup"` field.

```js
const pickup = document.querySelector('#pickup')
const dropoff = document.querySelector('#dropoff')
const origin = document.querySelector('#origin')
const destination = document.querySelector('#destination')
const submit = document.querySelector('#submitForm')

pickup.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  origin.value = e.target.value
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pickup">Pickup</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pickup" aria-describedby="pickupHelp">
    <input type="text" class="form-control hidden" id="origin" value="empty">
    <small id="pickupHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your pickup location</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pickup">Drop-off</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dropoff" aria-describedby="dropoffHelp">
    <input type="text" class="form-control hidden" id="destination" value="">
    <small id="dropoffHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your drop-off location</small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But what is wrong with that code? what does not work for you?

Comment: Works for me (although I have to remove the `hidden` class in order to *see* the input so I know the value is changing).

Comment: Same, it works, you just need to remove the class `hidden` from #origin (in order to see it).

Comment: @LuísRamalho — The value changes even if you don't remove that class. It just isn't visible in the UI.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say @Quentin :) -- should've added "in order to see the text"

Comment: Of course, it is Franco. Whatever is possible using a JS library or framework is possible with just javascript as well. JS libraries and frameworks do their 'magic' using pure javascript. So every magic you see happening is coming from the execution of pure javascript.

Comment: I understand. Thank you all for the help. I can see that the elements value update but what I cant see is that the ```value="empty"``` attribute in the inspector changing. if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I was looking for. Sorry for not clearly stating what I wanted to do.

```js
pickup.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
//changed to .defaultValue instead of just .value
    origin.defaultValue = e.target.value
})
```